# Failure connecting Mikrotik to Strongswan using IPSec

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, mikrotik

hope you are doing well.

I am trying to connect a Mikrotik RB2011RM to Strongswan running on a cloud server.  I cannot get past Phase 1.

I have searched through google and found some great examples and still cannot figure out what is the problem.  Right now I have an example from Strongswan setup will no luck still.

Hoping someone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are the particulars:

The RB2011 is on my home network and the Strongswan is on a VPS at a 3rd party provider.  I have gone down to simple PSK auth to try to get it to work.

StrongSwan ipsec.conf:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
        charondebug="all"

# Add connections here.

conn %default
        ikelifetime=60m
        keylife=20m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1
        authby=secret
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no

conn tower-vpn
      ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp1024!
      esp=aes256-sha2_256!
      left=107.161.22.19
      leftsubnet=107.161.22.19/32
      leftid=@vpnsvr.*******.org
      right=206.83.248.2
      rightid=206.83.248.2
      rightsubnet=10.232.70.0/24
      auto=add
```

ipsec.secrets

```
# This file holds shared secrets or RSA private keys for authentication.

# RSA private key for this host, authenticating it to any other host
# which knows the public part.


: RSA vpn-server.key.pem   # VPN server key generated above

# <user id> : EAP <secret>

10.232.70.1 : PSK "***********"   
206.83.248.2 : PSK "***********"
```

Mikrotik Config:

```
Mike Myers <netnutmike@gmail.com>
4:55 PM (0 minutes ago)
to me

# may/17/2022 16:54:00 by RouterOS 6.49.6
# software id = YFGT-A2YC
#
# model = 2011UiAS
# serial number = 6089057B8541
/ip ipsec profile
add dh-group=modp1024 enc-algorithm=aes-256 hash-algorithm=sha256 name=\
    profile_1 nat-traversal=yes
/ip ipsec peer
add address=107.161.22.19/32 name=CloudVPN profile=profile_1
/ip ipsec proposal
set [ find default=yes ] auth-algorithms=sha256 enc-algorithms=aes-256-cbc
/ip ipsec identity
add my-id=address:206.83.248.2 peer=CloudVPN secret=**********
/ip ipsec policy
add dst-address=10.232.0.0/23 level=use peer=CloudVPN src-address=\
    10.232.70.0/24 tunnel=yes
```

Strongswan log:

```
 received packet: from 206.83.248.2[500] to 107.161.22.19[500] (128 bytes)
May 17 20:52:49 hamsocial charon: 06[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V ]
May 17 20:52:49 hamsocial charon: 06[IKE] no IKE config found for 107.161.22.19...206.83.248.2, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
May 17 20:52:49 hamsocial charon: 06[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1363442209 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
May 17 20:52:49 hamsocial charon: 06[NET] sending packet: from 107.161.22.19[500] to 206.83.248.2[500] (40 bytes)
May 17 20:52:59 hamsocial charon: 14[NET] received packet: from 206.83.248.2[500] to 107.161.22.19[500] (128 bytes)
May 17 20:52:59 hamsocial charon: 14[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V ]
May 17 20:52:59 hamsocial charon: 14[IKE] no IKE config found for 107.161.22.19...206.83.248.2, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
May 17 20:52:59 hamsocial charon: 14[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1065270688 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
May 17 20:52:59 hamsocial charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 107.161.22.19[500] to 206.83.248.2[500] (40 bytes)
May 17 20:53:09 hamsocial charon: 07[NET] received packet: from 206.83.248.2[500] to 107.161.22.19[500] (128 bytes)
May 17 20:53:09 hamsocial charon: 07[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V ]
May 17 20:53:09 hamsocial charon: 07[IKE] no IKE config found for 107.161.22.19...206.83.248.2, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
May 17 20:53:09 hamsocial charon: 07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3707957538 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
May 17 20:53:09 hamsocial charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 107.161.22.19[500] to 206.83.248.2[500] (40 bytes)
```

Mikrotik Log:

```
16:53:49 ipsec,error phase1 negotiation failed due to time up 10.0.0.254[500]<=>107.161.22.19[500] be65b4bf51adec2d:0000000000000000
16:53:57 ipsec,info initiate new phase 1 (Identity Protection): 10.0.0.254[500]<=>107.161.22.19[500]
```

Comment: The MikroTik box uses IKEv1 (ID_PROT), so either make it use IKEv2 if possible, or try to configure `keyexchange=ikev1` or `keyexchange=ike` so strongSwan accepts IKEv1 messages.